# Position the dropbox menu

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to position the opened dropdown menu? I mean as I click on the `<select>`, the options appear in the box which is located over the selected option. Is there any solution to move this options box down?

This is what happens:

[image]

What I want to happen:

[image]

Sample here : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dg905dh/)

```
<select>
    <option>BMW</option>
    <option>Mercedes</option>
    <option>Ferrari</option>
    <option>Audi</option>
    <option>Fiat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Was not able to reproduce your problem in Chrome version 50.0.2657.0 (canary). Maybe it's a OS X problem only? Which would make sense, as browsers handle stuff like this differently.

Comment: @Snorlax You're right, I am in OSX, but in general is there any way to position the box?

Comment: Read Tom's answer below. You cannot move it unless you create a custom dropdown (which is farely easy as well). You don't even need any fancy libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to position the option dropdown box from a select when using native controls, it's part of the built in control. You'd have to create custom select boxes to control the positioning of the dropdown.